# where can i find my back up for my ipod?

Tags: backup, ipod

my computer had to be restored to factory setting and i had a ton of music on it. Well i backed my ipod up to my computer, because it said it would have a complete back up on my computer. For anyone who has done this, where could i find it? or what was yours under?

Answer (score 1):

In normal situations you can just connect your iPod with your mac and there should be a restore button.

Furthermore iTunes in general does not backup music in the normal backup since it is just copying the music out of your iTunes library.

Nevertheless the folder where your backups are is in

```
 /Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup
```